# Preventing 10-Minute-Mails From Singing Up (Webpage)

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, spam-prevention

Recently people have used services to generate 10-Minute mails to signup on my website. I would like to separate proper mails from spam-mails. I know that Discord has such a system, when signing up with a mail it would just say "invalid mail" and block you from signing up.

I have tried to find a solution on the web, but this doesn't seem to be a popular topic.

**My first idea:**
Having a whitelist of mails like Gmail, GMX, iCloud, etc, and prompt users that don't have one of these emails with an additional phone number request (or something similar). This would help keeping spam out of my website.

**My second idea:**
Having bots that scrape the most popular spam-mail-generators, and generates a list of blacklisted emails. This seems quite difficult because I would have to make an individual scraper for each website. Most websites also get different domains every day so I would have to scrape the sites regularly.

I couldn't find any APIs or any help in general on the internet.

Recently I found out that there also are public phone numbers. My next step would be to detect these too.

Is there a way of doing what I'm trying to? Should I maybe completely change my method of preventing spam registrations on my website (I'm already using reCaptcha, I mean preventing humans that have bad intentions of spam, etc)?

Kind regards,
Florian Covy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either [deep-email-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-email-validator) or [email-deep-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-deep-validator) ON TOP OF a confirmation email system. Note that using these validators alone is not enough, but they provide a first layer of "security" against disposable emails.

Comment: Both links are the same module? And this module doesn't seem to detect 10-minute mails, which is one thing I would want to do. The module you meant probably is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-email-validator which seems to be perfect!

Comment: Oh yeah, oops. As for the 10 minute mail thing, I would assume "disposable email blacklists" means things like 10 minute mail, but maybe I'm wrong, since I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The [testmail.top](https://testmail.top/en/example) API works exactly according to the two ideas that you described:

```
1. Domain is checked for availability in the whitelist
2. Then the domain is checked against the blacklist
```

This is what makes it possible to reduce the probability of error to 0%. The base of temporary and trusted mails is updated daily.

All you need to determine the temporary mail is to send a **GET request**:

```
https://api.testmail.top/domain/check/data=example@mail.com&ip=8.8.8.8
```

With **authorization header**:

```
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX
```

And in response you will receive a message like this if the mail turns out to be **temporary**:

```
{
    "error": 0,
    "result": false,
    "message": "This domain is in Blacklist"
}
```

You will receive such an answer if the mail turns out to be **trusted** (something like gmail.com or yahoo.com):

```
{
    "error": 0,
    "result": true,
    "message": "This domain is in Whitelist"
}
```

I have described error codes and more detailed instructions on this [page](https://testmail.top/en/example#errors)